# Printing Java String return array of int

Tags: java, hash

I used the function below to calculate a hash of password. My problem is when I try to print hashcode I get an array of int even that the hash variable is of type String.

```
private static String getHashCode(String password) {
    String hash = "";
    try {
        MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
        byte [] digest = md5.digest(password.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        hash = Arrays.toString(digest);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(hash);
    return hash;
}
```

Comment: I think you are getting a String in which all entries of your array are printed. Maybe you want a hex ouput of your byte array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you called `Arrays.toString` which returns a direct string representation of the array.

Instead, you probably want a hexadecimal representation of the `byte[]` array, which you can do with something like this (untested):

```
StringBuilder hexString = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < digest.length; i++) {
    String hex = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & digest[i]);
    if (hex.length() == 1) {
        hexString.append('0');
    }
    hexString.append(hex);
}
String hash = hexString.toString();
```

Comment: I didn't know that. So I will do like you said. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is normal. You are calling:

`hash = Arrays.toString(digest);`

So you get a string which represents the array `digest` in a string form.

Answer (score 1):

As you see  byte [] digest is a byte array that contain int values after that you transform to string so confert array of int into string so it's normal....